# 'Invalid object or resource' with bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm making a PHP frontend for a MySQL database. I've got a table called "Regions" which contains RegionID (int), Name (string), and Country (string). I'm trying to put a <select> list onto a form containing all the regions as options, using <optgroup>'s to group regions by country. I've already done it successfully by nested plain queries, and now I'm trying to get my head around prepared statements.

What I've got so far is:

```
// $DB is database object, already connected
// Error checking will be worked into this once I've worked out the basics...

$stmt_country = $DB->stmt_init();
$stmt_country->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM Regions ORDER BY Country ASC");
$stmt_country->execute();
$stmt_country->bind_result($CountryName);

$stmt_region = $DB->stmt_init();
$stmt_region->prepare("SELECT RegionID,Name FROM REGIONS WHERE Country=? ORDER BY Name ASC");
$stmt_region->bind_param("s",$CountryName);

echo "<select name=\"RegionID\">\n";

while ($stmt_country->fetch()) {
    // Start 'country' option group

    echo "<optgroup label=\"$CountryName\">\n";

    // Execute the 'regions' query using the 'country' parameter

    $stmt_region->execute();
    $stmt_region->bind_result($RegionID,$RegionName);

    while ($stmt_region->fetch()) {
        // Output the regions matching that country 

        echo "<option value=\"$RegionID\">$RegionName</option>\n";
        }

    echo "</optgroup>\n";
    }

echo "</select>\n";
```

However when I run this I'm getting:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): invalid object or resource
```

on the `$stmt_region->bind_param("s",$CountryName)` line.

With some commenting out of code, I've got just the `$stmt_country` half of it working (i.e. outputs just the optgroups for each country), and then bodging in a value for `$CountryName`, the `$stmt_region` half of it works by itself, but I can't get both halves working together. Can someone please advise where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Out of interest, what happens if you skip the `stmt_init()` call and do `$stmt_region = $DB->prepare("SELECT ...");`?

Comment: Can you add some debugging `print` statements to show that `$CountryName`'s value has been properly set before relying on it in the second query?

Comment: @DaveRandom - I'd wondered that too. I'm learning by copying examples and tutorials I've found, some use stmt_init(), some don't. Does it make any difference if I call stmt_init or not?

Comment: @sarnold - yes I'd tried that and $CountryName was being output properly, it just wasn't being fed into the second query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im pretty sure you cant have 2 staments bound on the same connection resource until after you have gone through the entire result set. Because of that your second `stmt_init()` isnt actually returning a statement.

It looks like all the data is on the same table so there is no need for 2 queries.

If the data were on two tables then there would still be no need for 2 queries as oyu could use a join:

What you can do, and should do even if this is not the case is use a join to get everything at once:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.RegionID, r.Country 
FROM Regions r, Country c
WHERE c.NAME = r.Country 
ORDER BY r.Country ASC
```

In either case you can get a reult set looking like:

```
RegionID    Country    Name
----------------------------------
1           US         Ohio
2           US         California
3           US         New York
4           CN         Guan Dong
5           CN         Hunan
6           CN         Szechuan
```

Because of the ordering you can use a single loop comparing the previous `Country` to the current to determine when to close/open your opt group tags.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of not being able to make a 2nd query until the results of the 1st were fetched. I've got it working now by using $Countries=get_result() on the first query before setting up the 2nd one, and fetching the results from this rather than from $stmt_country.

Comment: Can you show an example of your last point about comparing the previous Country to determine optgroup tags? Sorry I'm picking up bits as I go along with this whole thing!

Comment: Actually, ignore that last comment, that was late last night and I've got my head round it this morning. Thanks for your help!